# Can (should?) a Restful API call it's own endpoints?

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-web-api

I have an API project created in C#. There's a desire to "simplify" something that it does which would mean creating a new API endpoint, which in the background would call several existing endpoints within the same API.

I'm concerned that this sort of recursion, an API calling itself, is bad practice and it'd be a better solution to have applications that make use of the API call the existing endpoints individually and manage the returned data within their own separate application logic. Am I right to be concerned?

Thanks

Comment: each endpoint can be treated as a service. That said, you should read up on Service Oriented Architecture (SOA)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There is a whole lot of "it depends" in the answer.

If you moved logic out of your controllers and into shared libraries would it make sense for these two libraries to call one another directly, or would they be in the same library?

If they're in the same library and the data they access should all be in that same service, then I would call within the library.